# Does fprintf() always write over what's already in a file?

Tags: c

Say I have the following:

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fprintf(fp1,"%i\n",counter);
```

When I run my program, it writes the counter to the file. But when I run the program again and end up with a different counter, instead of writing that counter below the first one, it just replaces the first one. Is there a way to make it not just replace whats already in the file each time I run the program?

Comment: you can open your output file in append mode. See more @http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 2):

Set the file access mode to `"a"` (append) as shown below:

```
FILE *fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "a");
```

Comment: That's not a valid mode. You must have exactly one of `r` (read), `w` (overwrite), or `a` (append only).   There can also be a `+` and a `b` in each case.